Plymouth shows stacktrace for no apparent reason
I've got a beautiful seamless startup experience with Arch & KDE Plasma 6.1, thanks to Plymouth. But after recent updates (I believe to kernel 6.9.x), the splash screen is interrupted by a stacktrace. The trace doesn't seem to offer any meaningful information on what went wrong. Also, Plymouth works fine regardless.
The stacktrace doesn't show up in logs, so I've made a photo of it - ignore the 'no key available' message, I was hitting return to see if it froze, but it didn't, it was still waiting for my passphrase:

Then there was some mention of Plymouth exiting abnormally in journalctl:
Jul 23 12:21:31 archlinux systemd-coredump[935]: Process 311 (plymouthd) of user 0 terminated abnormally with signal 11/SEGV, processing...
Jul 23 12:21:31 archlinux systemd-coredump[935]: Due to PID 1 having crashed coredump collection will now be turned off.
Jul 23 12:21:31 archlinux systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA System Management Interface...
Jul 23 12:21:31 archlinux systemd-coredump[935]: Resource limits disable core dumping for process 311 (plymouthd).
Jul 23 12:21:31 archlinux systemd-coredump[935]: [] Process 311 (plymouthd) of user 0 terminated abnormally without generating a coredump.

I also tried adding the kernel option plymouth.debug. This doesn't seem to provide much more insight. There is an interesting thing, it has a lot of mentions like this:
00:00:46.600 ../plymouth/src/libply-splash-core/ply-terminal-emulator.c:989: terminal escape character: carriage return

This suggests I'm hitting return? Because I was not.
Here's the entire log: https://pastebin.com/rpvnkgZ3
There are also some mentions of a timeout. This is interesting, because when I boot, the Plymouth splash screen comes up normally, in proper resolution etc., but after a few seconds, it cuts to the stacktrace. Then, when I enter my passphrase, it continues to boot normally. Curiously, if I use the plymouth.debug kernel option, it fails to boot, it then hangs on 'Reached Target Graphical Interface'.
Any ideas what this could be? I've tried reinstalling Plymouth, but that made no difference. I also rebuilt initramfs (multiple times, obviously to get the debug log), also no difference.

usually when something very stable like plymouth crashes, chances are that oy uexchanged a library with a not 100% compatible version. Did you make sure you did a full upgrade when you updated something in your Arch, or might there be packages that were left unupgraded?

Yes, everything's up-to-date. Just did the latest updates this morning, no change unfortunately. I also suspect there is some compatibility issue, but I can't quite determine where.

I must admit I'm really not an experienced arch user. Maybe an update should have regenerated the initrd, but didn't? Don't know how to do that manually on arch

Also regenerated initrd manually, to be sure. Didn't solve it, unfortunately.

FWIW: I finally resolved this by removing all of Plymouth, including dependencies, and then re-installing with default options. However, when I wanted to set a different theme (taken from the AUR, which in turn comes from https://github.com/adi1090x/plymouth-themes) I ran into the same issue. Also, selecting one of the themes shipped with KDE, it would show the same problem. After trying out some themes, it looks like when it's a theme with text/fonts, it will exhibit the issue, while themes without are fine. Therefore, it must be something with font rendering/UI that broke in a recent update.

it would be cool if you copied the content of your comment to an answer: that way, you could mark your question as answered (you can accept your own answer after 24h), and people in the future can find it more easily

@MarcusMüller it's more of a work-around than an answer to my question, because it will still show that stacktrace when I load particular themes. So the question still remains what the stacktrace is about and how to solve it.
